# Poco library and tls 1.3

Tags: openssl, poco-libraries

Does the poco library support communication using TLS version 1.3?
I have scanned the release notes but can not find any information about it.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's too late but since v1.10.0:
[ReleaseNotes](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/99100-ReleaseNotes.html)

> The NetSSL_OpenSSL library supports TLS 1.3 with OpenSSL 1.1.1 or
> later. The NetSSL_Win library supports TLS 1.3 if it's supported by the underlying SChannel implementation.